# Normed vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $(E,\Vert\Vert)$ be a normed vector space  and $u\not =0,v\not=0 \in E$. 
How can I show that 
$$\Vert u +v\Vert \leq \Vert u\Vert +\Vert v\Vert -2 \left(\Vert {\frac{u}{\Vert v\Vert }+\frac{v}{\Vert v\Vert }}\Vert \right)\min(\Vert u\Vert ,\Vert v\Vert )$$

Comment: But that's not even true... Are you sure you didn't misspelled anything?

Comment: @Börge I saw that the first part ($\Vert u +v \Vert \leq \Vert u\Vert +\Vert v\Vert $) is always true, due to the definiton of a norm, then I tried to assume that $\Vert u \Vert$ is the minimum of the two... at the end, after few calculations I have $\Vert u + v \Vert \leq \Vert v \Vert - \Vert u\Vert $ that is false

Comment: Where does that forumula came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with euclidean norm and take $u=(1,0),v=(0,1)$ then right part of the equality is $2-2.\sqrt{2}$ and the left side is $2$ hence the conhclusion collapses

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have miscalculated something. Since $||u+v||=||u||+||v||$ whenever $u=cv$ for some $c\ge 0$, your formula is easily seen to be false by letting $u=v\ne 0$.